# Neo4j REST API with PHP

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

How can we use the nodes we create in a code in subsequent `PHP`s?

I have created a node in `register.php`

```php
$client = new Client(new Transport('localhost', 7474));

$user = new Node($client);
$user->setProperty('name', 'Josh Adell')->save();
```

Now,I want to use this node in an other file `login.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend adding your nodes to an index. It will make looking them up later much easier. Then you can search on your index. As your graph gets larger, you won't want to manually traverse all nodes in your graph starting at the first node. Indexes provide huge speed increases over manual graph traversal.

```
$client = new Client(new Transport('localhost', 7474));

$user = new Node($client); 
$user->setProperty('name', 'Josh Adell')->save();

$userIndex = new Everyman\Neo4j\Index\NodeIndex($client, 'users');
$userIndex->save();

$userIndex->add($user, 'name', $user->getProperty('name'));
```

Login Page:

```
$client = new Client(new Transport('localhost', 7474));
$queryString = "START user=node:users('name: \"Josh Adell\"') RETURN user";
$query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString);
$result = $query->getResultSet();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['x']->getProperty('name') . "\n";
}
```